# Programmatically Replacing a JavaScript Method with Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to use Java to replace some JavaScript in a file. The steps I'm taking are basically like this:

1. Read in a file (it's an .asp file with JavaScript in it that is generated from another system)
2. Replace the unwanted JavaScript function with one I do want
3. Write it back out over the file that was originally generated

I'm having trouble with step 2 because my code seems to freak out on the replaceAll method. Let's say I want to replace this method:

```
function sayHi() {
    alert('hi');
}
```

...with something like this:

```
function sayHi() {
    alert("Hello, World!");
}
```

I have code that looks like this:

```
private static final String REPLACEMENT_METHOD =
        "function sayHi() {\n" +
        "   alert('Hello, World!');\n" +
        "}";

private static final String METHOD_TO_REPLACE =
        "function sayHi() {\n" +
        "   alert('hi');\n" +
        "}";

String content = // Get the contents from the file...

content = content.replaceAll(METHOD_TO_REPLACE, REPLACEMENT_METHOD);
```

The problem I'm running into is that the string that I want to replace is being interpreted as a regex (it's just literal text, but it is, of course, interpreted as a regex) and it bails out on me. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find the correct syntax to escape the special characters properly and still get it to match the way I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should try with a substring of the entire match and then slowly work towards the entire match:
Start with a simpler METHOD_TO_REPLACE like "hello", and just a small part of REPLACEMENT_METHOD such as "function sayHi". If that works, then you can slowly increase the matching criteria until you figure what doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use quote operators around your match pattern:

```
private static final String METHOD_TO_REPLACE =
    "\\Q" +
    "function sayHi() {\n" +
    "   alert('hi');\n" +
    "}" +
    "\\E";
```

By the way,

```
function sayHi() {
    alert("Hello, World!");
}
```

isn't going to work in Java. You probably want:

```
void sayHi() {
    alert("Hello, World!");
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about these quotes operators. About the sayHi function: he's using Javascript, there is no void, only function.

Comment: Beautiful! That allows me to do the replacement exactly as I wanted. I had been looking at the Pattern API and completely missed that part, but I see it there, now. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielPereira - OP said that the goal was to replace JavaScript functions with Java.

Comment: @TedHopp Yes, and sayHi is one of the Javascript functions he wants to replace, not a function written in Java.

Comment: @DanielPereira I was referring to `REPLACEMENT_METHOD` in the question; as I understand it, that's supposed to be the Java replacement.

Comment: He's using the word "with" in the sense of "Drive a nail __with__ a hammer", i.e. he wants to use Java to replace a JavaScript function.

Comment: @Barmar - Ah. It's amazing how once I (mis)read something one way, it takes a hammer (or 2-by-4 upside the head) to get me to read it with a different sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @TedHopp I was confused by why you wanted to give me the Java version of the method until I re-read my post - not a good use of grammar, on my part. In the end, I want to *use* Java to replace a JavaScript method with a different JavaScript method. I have updated my original post to make that more clear. Thanks again for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Method replaceAll indeed uses the first parameter as a pattern.

So, you have the following solutions.

1. escape your patterns manually. As far as I can see it is not too hard in your case.
2. try to do this programmatically using `Pattern.quote()`
3. use `String.replace()` in loop instead of `replaceAll()`. Method `replace()` works with plain strings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the backslash `\`?

Comment: I have. The compiler seems to be complaining about the '{' on the first line - I get a "number expected" error. If I try to escape that and make it '\{', I get a new compiler error: "Illegal escape character in a string literal". If I add a second escape character, so it becomes '\\{', it compiles. Unfortunately, that changes my matching pattern to be "function sayHi() \{" and that won't match the way I want it to.